# Linked servers and SQL Server 2005 on localhost

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to run SQL Server 2005 on localhost, with a schema of it's own, and then use data from another remote server?

Can this be achieved with linked servers?

Im trying to set up a proper sandbox on localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linked servers should work for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to connect in to more than one remote server for data?

If yes, I think the linked server option is an OK way to go. I say OK because you would probably do better to create a sandbox on one of the remote servers then create linked servers from it. It seems like a waste to setup SQL Server on your desktop/laptop. However, if space/permissions is an issue, you may not have a choice.

If it is only one server, why not create the sandbox on it and connect and work in it using SQL Management Studio. Although it is a weird path to setup the management studio without installing the full SQL server, you can do it. This way you won't have to actually log into the remote server (bad idea for a number of reasons).

If you do setup the linked servers, here are a couple of snags I ran in to that may help:

- If the SQL server is an instanced setup use brackets when writing it out, e.g. [SERVERNAME/INSTANCE]
- Use an alias when pulling from a table or view from the linked server because you can only have 4 parts in the naming convention, so, [servername/instance].database.dbo.table.field is 5 parts and will throw an error.